# CALayer not visible if added after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-animation, calayer

I've got a class called `TiledScrollViewController`, which is not at all related to `UIScrollView`. In that view controller, I'm attempting to add a CALayer to the `bgImageView` property on my view controller from a callback elsewhere in the app by calling `newCylon`. Yes. Cylon. It's a silly app, but it's an important question.

This is how I create my new cylon layers.

```
-(CALayer *)newCALayerWithNSString:(NSString *)imageName
                  andCATransform3D:(CATransform3D)transform
                        andCGPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CALayer *outputLayer = [CALayer layer];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    outputLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img].CGColor;
    [outputLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
    outputLayer.transform = transform;
    [outputLayer setPosition:point];
    [outputLayer setZPosition:5.0];

    return outputLayer;
}
```

And here is how I call that in `newCylon`.

```
-(CALayer *)newCylon{
    NSLog(@"NEW CYLON");
    CALayer *cylon = [self newCALayerWithNSString:@"Cylon"
                                 andCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(.3, -.3, .3)
                                       andCGPoint:CGPointMake(.5*screenWidth,0)];

    [self.bgImageView.layer addSublayer:cylon]; // this works, but I don't see anything

    [self moveCylon:cylon];
    return cylon;
}
```

Now. I have one cylon `CALayer` which displays and animates because I call `[self newCylon]` inside of `viewDidLoad`. But if I call `newCylon` anywhere else, nothing shows up. I can verify via `[self.bgImageView.layer sublayers]` that the `sublayers` array is changing in size. But nothing is appearing on screen except that first cylon.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should name your arguments for what they are used for, not what type they are.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[CATransaction flush]` to the end of my `newCylon` method fixed everything.